# Setting table width with pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I am using pgfplotstable to create a table for the following data:

```
Species         Moles (1)    Moles (2)    Moles (3)
Ca++            1.8887e-4    1.9476e-4    3.4462e-2
CaCl+           3.7537e-5    3.8262e-5    6.7001e-3
CaCl2(aq)       7.2626e-6    7.3202e-6    1.2881e-3
CaCO3(aq)       6.6707e-6    2.1461e-11   6.5734e-6
Cl-             1.9999e+0    1.9999e+0    1.9904e+0
CO2(aq)         9.8315e-8    7.5467e-1    7.4064e-1
H+              4.6749e-10   8.7625e-4    1.7078e-5
H2O(l)          5.5508e+1    5.5434e+1    5.5391e+1
HCO3-           4.2763e-4    1.7492e-3    8.8265e-2
Mg++            1.6018e-4    1.6223e-4    1.3874e-3
MgCl+           3.3875e-5    3.3911e-5    2.8623e-4
MgCO3(aq)       2.0802e-6    1.0114e-11   9.8367e-8
Na+             2.0000e+0    2.0000e+0    2.0000e+0
OH-             4.2783e-4    2.3555e-10   1.1323e-8
```

However, I can't figure out how to specify that the **table width** should be the **text width**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [latex how to make table as the same width as the textwidth?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20225/latex-how-to-make-table-as-the-same-width-as-the-textwidth)

Comment: Not a duplicate I would say - I'm asking here how to set the table width when using the `pgfplotstable` package.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to first clear the column type defaults and then say, use `tabularx` type of table. That needs two additional options to change the default table commands. The rest is using rules at the bottom and up.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tabularx,booktabs}


\begin{document}
\noindent%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[column type=,
                      begin table={\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X c c c}},
                      end table={\end{tabularx}},
                      columns/Species/.style={string type},
                      every head row/.style={before row=\toprule},
                      every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
                      ]{
Species         {Moles (1)}  {Moles (2)}  {Moles (3)}
Ca++            1.8887e-4    1.9476e-4    3.4462e-2
CaCl+           3.7537e-5    3.8262e-5    6.7001e-3
CaCl2(aq)       7.2626e-6    7.3202e-6    1.2881e-3
CaCO3(aq)       6.6707e-6    2.1461e-11   6.5734e-6
Cl-             1.9999e+0    1.9999e+0    1.9904e+0
CO2(aq)         9.8315e-8    7.5467e-1    7.4064e-1
H+              4.6749e-10   8.7625e-4    1.7078e-5
H2O(l)          5.5508e+1    5.5434e+1    5.5391e+1
HCO3-           4.2763e-4    1.7492e-3    8.8265e-2
Mg++            1.6018e-4    1.6223e-4    1.3874e-3
MgCl+           3.3875e-5    3.3911e-5    2.8623e-4
MgCO3(aq)       2.0802e-6    1.0114e-11   9.8367e-8
Na+             2.0000e+0    2.0000e+0    2.0000e+0
OH-             4.2783e-4    2.3555e-10   1.1323e-8
}
\end{document}
```

[image]