# pfgplotstable: alignment string rendering in table

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am trying to render a page width table, and getting the alignment string in the render.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[letterpaper, inner=18mm, outer=18mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}


\begin{document}


\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, string type,                                       
begin table={\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xccccccccccc}},
  end table={\end{tabularx}},
every even row/.style={before row = {\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}}, 
font=\footnotesize                                           
]{dataFile.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image: alignment variables "ccc..." in the table.]

Answer (score 1):

This SE question seems to be around the same topic:

[Setting table width with pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132546)

As you did not provide a MWE, my first guess would be to play with `column type=`.

Comment: This did fix the problem, thanks! One question, since I am new here, I am not sure what an MWE is.