# Setting table textwidth with \pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable, textwidth

I am trying to fit a table into textwidth using pgfplotstable. The code I found in this forum [(here)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132539/setting-table-width-with-pgfplotstable) somehow produces red lines and I do not know why this is the case.
[image]

This is how the results looks like. I do not understand what happens top/left. Also do you happen to know how to left-align the columns?
[image: Result]

The biggest difference between my code and the code I found is that I am storing my data in a csv file. Any suggestions and solutions are highly appreciated. This is my code:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tabularx,booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{\textbf{Caption} }
\label{caption}
\footnotesize   
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    column type=,
     begin table={\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X c c c c}},
       end table={\end{tabularx}},
      multicolumn names, % allows to have multicolumn names
      col sep=comma, column type={l}, % the separator in the .csv file + column raggedleft
      display columns/0/.style={  column name=$ $, %first column because it is string type
        column type={l},string type}, 
      every head row/.style={
        before row= \toprule,% have a rule at top
        after row={
            \si{\ampere} & \si{\volt}\\ % the units separated by &
            \midrule} % rule under units
            },
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}, % rule at bottom
    ]{Datafile.csv} % filename/path to file
\raggedright
\newline
\footnotesize{\textit{Sources}}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is missing `\documentclass`. It also looks like you want to add `\usepackage{situnitx}`. Please include the csv file as well

Comment: The red lines are from your editor telling you there's an error at that point in the code (hence the ⌧ on the left). I wouldn't read too much into the exact location of the highlighting. The log file will be more informative as to the actual error